# Using ? : in C for the first time

Tags: c, conditional-operator

I just started classes at my school in programming and I learned how to use `? :` for the first time. My first question is what this is called, because my prof didn't say what it is called.

Second, I'm writing a program that prints even when given an even number and odd when given an odd number. I wanted to write it like this

```
int main() {
    int x = 3;
    char *string;

    if (x % 2 == 0 ? string = "Even" : string = "Odd");

    printf("%d is %s", x, string);
}
```

the problem is I get an error `error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment` at `if (x % 2 == 0 ? string = "Even" : string = "Odd");` and it's the `string = "Odd"` part.

Am I not allowed to assign expressions to variables inside of `if( ? : )`? I want to keep my code short and not have to write it like

```
if (x % 2 == 0) {
    printf("%d is Even", x);
} else {
    printf("%d is Odd", x);
}
```

Comment: Don't use it if you don't understand it. A simple if is much more readable. _...what this is called..._ It's called ternary operator.

Comment: You don't use `?:` inside an `if` statement. It's used *instead* of an `if` statement when you want to assign the value to the same variable.

Comment: I figured it out, I literally just wrote ```string = (x % 2 == 0 ? "Even" : "Odd");```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If statement with ? and :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20887012/if-statement-with-and)

Comment: You can assign inside a conditional, but you need to add parentheses because of the default precedence.

Comment: `x % 2 == 0 ? (string = "Even") : (string = "Odd")`

Comment: @Barmar You don't actually *need* the first set of parentheses (though it's good to have them). From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence#cite_note-3): *The expression in the middle of the conditional operator (between ? and :) is parsed as if parenthesized: its precedence relative to ?: is ignored.*.

Comment: The `if()` instruction doesn't make sense, because its body is an empty instruction (consisting of a semicolon `;` alone). As a result the execution of `if(condition);` is precisely the same as `condition;`, whether the condition expression evaluates as _false_ or _true_..

Comment: @AdrianMole I believe in thorough use of parentheses in any complex expression like this, rather than depending on remembering the default precedence.

Comment: The C standard calls `? :` the conditional operator. It is a ternary operator. It is the only one in C, excluding function calls and `_Generic`, but it is not “the” ternary operator.

Comment: It is called the 'C obfuscation operator' :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This operator ?: is called in C the conditional operator. Programmers also call it as the ternary operator because the operator has three operands.

It is defined in C like

```
conditional-expression:
    logical-OR-expression
    logical-OR-expression ? expression : conditional-expression
```

The assignment operator has lower priority than the conditional operator.

This conditional operator in the if statement

```
if (x % 2 == 0 ? string = "Even" : string = "Odd");
```

is incorrect. In fact it is equivalent to

```
if ( ( x % 2 == 0 ? string = "Even" : string ) = "Odd" );
```

If the conditional operator within the if statement will be written correctly like

```
if (x % 2 == 0 ? string = "Even" : ( string = "Odd" ) );
```

nevertheless using the if statement itself does not make a sense because the expression within the if statement returns a pointer to a string literal that is not a null pointer. That is this if statement does not have a sub-statement and its condition is always evaluates to logical true.

You need just to write the following statement

```
x % 2 == 0 ? string = "Even" : ( string = "Odd" );
```

or for more readability like

```
x % 2 == 0 ? ( string = "Even" ) : ( string = "Odd" );
```

or simpler

```
string = x % 2 == 0 ? "Even" : "Odd";
```

Pay attention to that there is a difference in the definition of the conditional operator in C and in C++. In C++ the operator is defined like

```
conditional-expression:
    logical-or-expression
    logical-or-expression ? expression : assignment-expression
```

As you see the third expression may be an assignment expression. This means that you may write in C++ your conditional operator like

```
x % 2 == 0 ? string = "Even" : string = "Odd";
```

without enclosing in parentheses the third operand.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the ternary operator to invoke statements within each clause.  That is, don't use it as a replacement for if/else.  Use it for assignments:

Instead of this:

```
if (x % 2 == 0 ? string = "Even" : string = "Odd");
```

This:

```
string = (x % 2 == 0) ? "Even" : "Odd";
```

Comment: I *think* the 'formal' name (as per the Standard) is "conditional operator" but the term "ternary operator" is widely used.

Comment: Right after I wrote my question, I tried this and it worked. I felt silly after. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @AdrianMole _ternary_ operator is from how it looks, that is A ? B : C, where A contains the condition. The normal assignment can be called _binray_ operator as well. Yet there are no _quaternary_ and _quintuple_ and so on...

Answer (score 1):

It's called the "conditional operator". Because it's the <del>only</del> most known ternary operator (meaning it takes thee operands) in C and in C++ many people call it ternary operator.

> [Conditional Operator: ? :](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/conditional-operator-q?view=msvc-160)
>
> ```
> expression ? expression : expression
> ```
>
> The conditional operator (? :) is a ternary operator (it takes three
> operands). The conditional operator works as follows:
>
> The first operand is implicitly converted to bool. It is evaluated and
> all side effects are completed before continuing.
>
> If the first operand evaluates to true (1), the second operand is
> evaluated.
>
> If the first operand evaluates to false (0), the third operand is
> evaluated.
>
> The result of the conditional operator is the result of whichever
> operand is evaluated — the second or the third. Only one of the last
> two operands is evaluated in a conditional expression.

The rules for determining the type of the expression are a bit complicated. In simple terms its type is the common type between the second and third operand

Comment: It is not actually the only ternary operator. `(` and `)` used for function calls are an operator, per C 2018 6.5.2, and `foo(a, b)` has three operands. Similarly, `_Generic` is an operator, and `_Generic(foo, int: 0, default: 1)` has three operands.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I had no ideea, but now that I think about it it makes total sense. You learn something every day :)

Answer (score 1):

`?:` is called a ternary or conditional operator.

Last two lines can be merged into a single line like this:

```
printf("%d is %s\n", x, (x % 2 == 0) ? "Even" : "Odd");
```

You also don't need the `string` variable.